# JIRA - how to see 'who is doing what'?

Tags: jira, agile, scrum

We are using JIRA software for our project management. I don't see a good way to see 'who is doing what at this point of time'. Can anyone help? So I am in a need of some sort of dashboard where I can see activities of users.

Comment: If you're doing scrum, as your tag suggests, why not join the daily scrum and listen to what the team is working on. What the team is working n is far more important than what each individual is working on, if they're collaborating.

Comment: @jessehouwing: In my board, more than hundred tasks are there. Is there any way so that I can filter the 'In Progress' tasks only?

Comment: How to write a filter to keep only issues in 'In Progress' column?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Jira Agile as well, open the board view, it will show all the in progress work. If people have set the Assigned To field, you can see their name on the board as well. If multiple people are working on the same issue, they'll need to split it down into tasks and assign those.

Aren't they all in the "In Progress" column? If you need to you can configure a Quick Filter:

```
status="In Progress"
```

See:

- [Configuring Quick Filters.](https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile/jira-agile-user-s-guide/configuring-a-board/configuring-quick-filters)
- [Advanced Search](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA052/Advanced+Searching#AdvancedSearching-Status)

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly suggest you to create Rapid board which are available in Agile feature of Jira.

I would recommend you to use Either Scrum board or Kanban board where you can apply Swimlane filters.

There is another, On the dashboard, you can use activity plugins which will show you the activity log.
There are Group Time and Two Dimentional Filters are famous for it.

http://screencast.com/t/aOpTCz3aJgXQ

http://screencast.com/t/nBkkkb1AI1

Answer (score 0):

Add a two dimensional filter statistics gadget on a shared dashboard, and display Status (x axis) by Assignee (y axis). You'll get a nice table of who's doing what. Make sure you have a filter that selects the issues you're interested in.